# jQuery calling multiple setTimeout() sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around jQuery promises. I've created the following snippet to explore jQuery promises; informed by this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931115/jquery-execute-array-of-functions-sequentially-both-deferreds-and-non-deferred) entry.

```js
let q = [
  function () { setTimeout(function () { console.log("a - " + Date.now()); }, 5000); },
  function () { setTimeout(function () { console.log("b - " + Date.now()); }, 2500); },
  function () { setTimeout(function () { console.log("c - " + Date.now()); }, 0); }
];
    
function SerialCall(queue) {
  var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
   while (queue.length > 0) {
     d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
   }
}

SerialCall(q);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My understanding is that jQuery promises should hold off executing `b` and `c` while `a` is executing and subsequently hold off executing `c` while `b` is executing.

I was expecting the output to be `a, b, c` but I'm getting `c, b, a`. Note that I deliberately picked these delays ('a': 5000, 'b': 2500, 'c':0) to illustrate the fact that jQuery promises aren't blocking execution as planned.

What am I missing and how should I alter the code to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are going wrong is in thinking that a promise blocks execution. It doesn't. A promise is just another way to write a callback function; it doesn't add any magic beyond what JavaScript natively offers. (I'm not addressing `async`/`await` here, just "traditional" JavaScript.) All of your code runs to completion before any callbacks get called.

That's where you're running into trouble. Your `while` loop *runs to completion* before any of your queue functions ever get called:

```
while (queue.length > 0) {
    d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
}
```

If you want to have multiple functions get called with timeouts like you're doing, the best way to do it is not to fire all the `setTimeout()` calls all in a single gulp as your code does now. Instead, have each of the `callback` functions start the next `setTimeout()`. This way you only have a single timeout pending at any time, and when it fires you start the next one.

I wrote a jQuery plugin many years ago for this called `slowEach`. (It doesn't really depend on jQuery and the same technique would work for non-jQuery code too.)

The code doesn't use promises - it predates them by several years - but the principle is the same whether you use promises or traditional callbacks: start with a single `setTimeout()`, and then when its callback function gets called, start the next `setTimeout()`. This sequences the timeouts in the manner you were probably hoping the simple `while` loop would do.

The original `slowEach()` code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234260/1202830). Several people have made [improvements to the code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=slowEach) since then. In particular, [here is a version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372965/1202830) that adds an `onCompletion` callback so you get a different callback when the entire array has been processed.

This code doesn't use promises, but more importantly, it *works*. :-) It would be an interesting exercise to adapt the code to use promises.

But again, don't assume that JavaScript will wait for a promise to be done before it executes the next line of code. Unless you're using `async`/`await`, whatever ordinary loop you're running - `while`, `for`, whatever - will always run to completion before *any* of the callbacks - ordinary callbacks or promises - get run.

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: this answer only addresses the `I was expecting the output to be a, b, c but I'm getting c, b, a.`. It not solves the promise issue.

In your code, *whatever you hope for* (as explained by [Michael Geary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202830/michael-geary) above), 'a' outputs after 5 seconds, 'b' ouputs after 2.5 seconds and 'c' outputs immediatly.

If you want the 'a' to ouptut before the 'c', its waiting time (its *timeout*) must be shorter.

```js
let queue = [
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 0 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("a - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); },
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 2500 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("b - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); },
    function () { 
      let waitingTime = 5000 ;
      setTimeout(function () { console.log("c - " + Date.now()); }, waitingTime); }
];

function SerialCall(queue) {
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
    }
}

SerialCall(queue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, the clearer is your code, the simplier you can debug it, understand it. Look for instance:

```js
let queue = [
    function () { waitForMe('a', 0)    },
    function () { waitForMe('b', 2500) },
    function () { waitForMe('c', 5000) }
];

function SerialCall(queue) {
    var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        d = d.then(queue.shift()); // you don't need the `.done`
    }
}

function waitForMe(letter, someTime) {
  return setTimeout(function () { console.log(letter +" - " + Date.now()); }, someTime)
}

SerialCall(queue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I deliberately picked these delays to illustrate the fact that jQuery promises aren't blocking execution as planned.

Comment: Philcare, I'm trying to wrap my mind around jQuery promises. In my example the simple setTimeout() calls serve as proxies for more complex functions I wish to run sequentially. Your answer unfortunately doesn't help address this challenge.

Comment: Per my issue: "My understanding is that jQuery promises should hold off executing `b` and `c` while `a` is executing and subsequently hold off executing `c` while `b` is executing." How should I alter the code to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this jQuery extension to make sequential execution in a deferred queue.

You can use your list of timeout function as input of deferQueue, and execute them inside a main function (callable).

```js
$.fn.deferQueue = function(callable, options){
    options = Object(options);
  var it = (this.get() || [])[Symbol.iterator]();
  var stop = false, cond = null;
  var self = this;
  this.stop = function(){ stop=true; };
  this.end = function(_cond){ cond = _cond };
  var tid = 0;
  var iterate = function(){
   if(tid) clearTimeout(tid);
   var o = it.next();
   if(cond instanceof Function && cond(o.value)) return;
   if(o.done || stop) return;
   var d = callable.call(self, o.value);
   if(options.timeout) tid = setTimeout(function(){ d.reject('timeout'); }, options.timeout);
   if(options.success) d.done(options.success);
   if(options.fail) d.fail(options.fail);
   d[options.iterate || 'always'](iterate);
  }
  iterate();
  return this;
 }
  
  function log(text){
   console.log('Log: '+text);
  }
  function error(text){
   console.log('Error: '+text);
  }
  
  let q = [
  function (D) { setTimeout(function () { console.log("a - " + Date.now()); D.resolve('function 1'); }, 5000); },
  function (D) { setTimeout(function () { console.log("b - " + Date.now()); D.resolve('function 2') }, 2500); },
  function (D) { setTimeout(function () { console.log("c - " + Date.now()); D.resolve('function 3') }, 0); },
'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
'https://unreachabe_domain/image.png',
'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png',
null,
'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
];
  
  $(function(){       
    var
      display_timeout = parseInt($('#container').data('display-timeout')),
      loading_timeout = parseInt($('#container').data('loading-timeout'));
      
    $(q).deferQueue(function(e){
     var D = $.Deferred();
      if(typeof(e) == 'string') $('<img/>').attr('src',e).on('load',function(){ setTimeout(function(){ D.resolve(e); },display_timeout)}) 
        .on('error', function(){ D.reject(e) })
       .appendTo('#container');
      else if(e instanceof Function) e(D);
      D.done(log).fail(error);
      return D;
    },{iterate:'always',timeout:loading_timeout}).end(function(e){ return e===null; });
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  usage : $(&lt;iterable&gt;).deferQueue(&lt;function(element)&gt;,&lt;options&gt;)
  
  options:
      timeout: int(seconds)
      iterate: string(always | done | fail)
      success: function
      fail: function
</pre>
<div id="container" data-display-timeout="1000" data-loading-timeout="3000">

</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written